# For each XML node <suite> in <TestSuites> how can I get the text value of <suite><name> using Groovy

Tags: xml, groovy, tree, xml-parsing

I have the following code in Groovy where I have parsed in XML following this structure:

```
def xmlString = '''<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<result plugin="junit@1.28">
  <duration>8711.001</duration>
  <keepLongStdio>false</keepLongStdio>
  <build>null</build>
  <suites>
    <suite>
      <name>JavaScript Tests</name>
      <duration>5.331</duration>
      <timestamp>2019-10-01T20:24:36Z</timestamp>
      <id>0</id>
    </suite>
    <suite>
      <name>Whatever</name>
      <duration>5.331</duration>
      <timestamp>2019-10-01T20:24:36Z</timestamp>
      <id>2</id>
    </suite>
  </suites>
</result>'''

def masterXml = new XmlParser().parseText(xmlString)
masterXml.suites​.'*'.each{ suite ->
  def suiteName = suite
  println "GIVE ME SUITE NAME REEEEEEEEEEEEE: ${suiteName}"
}​
```

I'm trying to iterate through each `<suite>` in `<suites>` and for each suite get the `<name>` of the test suite that ran. I thought this would be extremely easy but apparently groovy uses some special syntax for whatever type of collection this is and, for me at least, it's actually extremely hard.

I did my best to read through the documentation here: https://groovy-lang.org/processing-xml.html#_simply_traversing_the_tree

and try to to build off of their examples, but I genuinely cannot get anything to work and just give me want I want.

I've made a groovy console for this problem here: https://groovyconsole.appspot.com/script/5074191896281088

and I've literally been playing with this for hours trying to figure it out. Please send help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have some non-printing character with code 63 immediately after `masterXml.suites`.

You can see it with this:

```
println "suites​.'*'".bytes // [115, 117, 105, 116, 101, 115, 63, 46, 39, 42, 39]
```

You also need to get the `name.text()`. Working version (I retyped the line with the non-printing character):

```
def masterXml = new XmlParser().parseText(xmlString)
masterXml.suites.'*'.each{ suite ->
  def suiteName = suite.name.text()
  println "GIVE ME SUITE NAME REEEEEEEEEEEEE: ${suiteName}"
}​
```

Edit: The character with code 63 should be a question mark. Which should be the `?.` operator, so should be valid Groovy. Some encoding issue creeping in somewhere. Interestingly, this gives the exact same sequence of bytes:

```
println "suites?.'*'".bytes // [115, 117, 105, 116, 101, 115, 63, 46, 39, 42, 39]
```

Comment: This code is correct. But it seems there is a problem in https://groovyconsole.appspot.com/ because this code fails there...

Comment: Thank you! I spent forever trying to type out the random sequence of periods and field names required to get these results. I'd swear I tried suite.name.text() too at some point, but it's definitely working now. I wonder if the weird bytes are leftover from me copying and pasting this code out of the online groovy console thing.